# Skip the primary phase if enough candidates withdraw

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, election

At the end of the nomination phase there were 12 nominees, so a primary phase was required. During the primary, 2 nominees withdrew their nomination. Doesn't that mean we can prematurely end the primary phase? It's no longer needed in order to reach the 10 top candidates.

Comment: Considering I made the same question a minute after years (then deleted it), I think it's safe to say I agree :)

Comment: @Wipqozn A minute after years? That's impressively late, no wonder you deleted it.

Comment: @GraceNote And I can't even edit it anymore. My failure will remain there for all to see.

Comment: I could edit it for you... for a price

Comment: 5 upvotes sound good ;)?

Comment: That sounds like turning around cause and effect. They withdrew because of the primary, so it seems effective to me

Comment: @Ivo the way I see it, the goal of the primary is to weed out all but 10 candidates. *We've already reached this goal*. If we want to change the primary's goal to encourage people withdraw, we should have applied it even if there were 10 nominees or less...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We won't be skipping the primary phase - it still serves a function if any other people wish to withdraw.

Comment: But if there had only been 10 people at the end of the nominations we wouldn't have needed that function?

Comment: @Michael - correct, the primary is working. It serves to reduce the number of candidates either by system elimination (top 10 by score) or by self elimination as a result of primary results.

Comment: -1 because I agree with Michael, and I don't quite understand your rationale... but accepting the answer because it does address the issue, thank you. It's not a big deal either way.

Comment: `It serves to reduce the number of candidates either by system elimination (top 10 by score) or by self elimination as a result of primary results.`  Could explain why "self elimination as a result of primary results" is needed when system elimination is not needed, despite the fact that only the need for the latter can trigger the former?

Comment: Perhaps this is similar to the idea behind hiding negative scores: it doesn't give the appearance of "great, we only needed to boot out two and now we got them out." (I will admit that if this is the case, it would make more sense to me if we also couldn't see when a candidate withdrew ... as it is, we still know which candidates dropped out to make it 10.)